# How to add or create a value in Spring Boot as a secret in Azure?

Tags: spring-boot, azure

I'm creating an Azure function in Spring Boot and I need to set a variable with a value in local environment and another value from a secret when the function is running in Azure.

I have this:

```java
JSONParser jsonparser = new JSONParser();
FileReader localSettingsReader = null;
localSettingsReader = new FileReader(".\\local.settings.json");
Object obj = jsonparser.parse(localSettingsReader);
JSONObject localsettingsobject = (JSONObject)obj;

// Get value from local environment
tenantId = (String) localsettingsobject.get("TENANTID");

// Get value from secret in Azure
???
```

How can I do this?

Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried any code to get value from secret? If tried, Could you share it here to resolve the error quickly.

Answer (score 0):

Try with below code which is working fine for me, and I am able to fetch the secret from Azure key vault.

```
@FunctionName("getSecret")
    public HttpResponseMessage run(@HttpTrigger(name = "req", methods = { HttpMethod.GET,
            HttpMethod.POST }, authLevel = AuthorizationLevel.ANONYMOUS) HttpRequestMessage<Optional<String>> request,
            final ExecutionContext context) {
        try {
            getToken();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        KeyVaultClient keyVaultClient = new KeyVaultClient(new KeyVaultCredentials() {
            public String doAuthenticate(String authorization, String resource, String scope) {
                // Use the access token for Key Vault
                return "Bearer " + access_token;
            }
        });

        SecretBundle secret = keyVaultClient.getSecret("<your key-vault 
 URL>/secrets/<your-secret-name>");
        System.out.println(secret + "\n");
        return request.createResponseBuilder(HttpStatus.OK).body(secret.value()).build();
    }
```